# When does a Google Play Android subscription actually auto-renew?

Tags: android, google-play, subscription

On the iOS platform, an auto-renewing in-app subscription renews 24 hours prior to expiry.

What is the equivalent time at which an auto-renewing in-app subscription renews on Android? I have a number of subscriptions within 24 hours of expiry, but they don't appear to be renewed/renewing. I have a block of more than 200 in-app subscriptions all within 24 hours of expiry but not a single one appears to have an extended expiration date when I reverify it with Google. It is unlikely that my user retention rate across this number of samples is actually 0%.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they're rather vague in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html):

> Monthly — Google Play bills the customer’s Google Checkout account at
>   the time of purchase and monthly subsequent to the purchase date
>   (exact billing intervals can vary slightly over time)

I feel like this means they would try to be as close to the original billing time as possible, although I couldn't be sure.